# Element loses its "rotateZ" value when "translateX" value is assigned - CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transforms

I have this test page which I'm working on.
As you can see from the snippet, I have the "**Share**" bar rotated on the Z axis with `transform: rotateZ(-90deg);` and left-positioned with `transform-origin:0 0;`.  (*Note*: this is the first time I use `transform-origin` and maybe I did something wrong(?)).

**What I want to do:**

When the page is scrolled up the "**Share**" bar should move to the left, outside the viewport, maintaining the `transform: rotateZ(-90deg);` property and when the page is scrolled down the "**Share**" bar should reappear in the same position. So it should stay shifted vertically when the transitions occur.

**The problem**:

When the page is scrolled up and the "**Share**" bar moves out of the viewport, the `transform: translateX(-120px);` property takes action as if the `transform: rotateZ(-90deg);` was never declared.

How can I make it stay vertically "*fixed*" during all the transitions, based on scrolling events?

**ALSO**: Why there is no `overflow-x` when the "**Share**" bar goes out the viewport?

**Edit**: I tried moving it with `left` and `right`, but in this case there's no `transition` time.

**The snippet** (*Note*: Go to the **bottom** of the css file for the `.share` element and its styling)

```js
const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
const nav = document.querySelector('nav');


burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
  nav.classList.toggle('active');
  burger.classList.toggle('hide');
  xicon.classList.toggle('active');
});

const xicon = document.querySelector('.xicon');
xicon.addEventListener('click', function() {
  nav.classList.toggle('active');
  xicon.classList.toggle('active');
  burger.classList.toggle('hide');
})



const header = document.querySelector('header');
let prev = window.pageYOffset;

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
  let current = window.pageYOffset;

  if(prev < current){
    header.classList.add('hide');
  }
  else {
    header.classList.remove('hide');
    }

    prev = current;

})


const shareThing = document.querySelector('.share');
let prevScroll = window.pageYOffset;

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  let currentScroll = window.pageYOffset;

  if(prevScroll < currentScroll) {
    shareThing.classList.add('hide');
    icons.classList.add('hide');
  }
  else {
    shareThing.classList.remove('hide');
    icons.classList.remove('hide');
  }

  prevScroll = currentScroll;

})


let share = document.querySelector('.share');
let icons = document.querySelector('.side');

share.addEventListener('click', () => {
  icons.classList.toggle('active');
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.logoandicon {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background: powderblue;
  padding: .7em 0;
}

.logo {
  margin-left: .5em;
}

.burger {
  margin-right: 1em;
  z-index: 2;
}

.burger.hide {
  display: none;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-family: verdana;
}

nav ul li {
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
}

nav {
  padding: 1em 0;
  line-height: 2em;
  background: lightgreen;
  display: none;
}

nav.active {
  display: block;
}

.xicon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1em;
  display: none;
}

.xicon.active {
  display: block;
}

header {
  width: 100vw;
  position: fixed;
}

header.hide {
  display: none;
}

main {
  padding-top: 4em;
}

.one {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

.two {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: green;
  color: white;
}

.three {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
}

.side {
  width: 30px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  background: black;
  display: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.side.active {
  display: flex;
}

.side.hide {
  display: none;
}

.share {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  transform: rotateZ(-90deg);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  padding: .15em 1em;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  transition: 1s;
}

.share.hide {
  transform: translateX(-120px);
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="logoandicon">
      <h1 class="logo">Logo</h1>
      <img src="menu.svg" class="burger" width="30px" alt="burger-icon">
      <img src="xicon.svg" class="xicon" width="27px" alt="x-icon">
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <main>

    <p class="share">Share</p>
    <div class="side">
      <div class="one">Fb</div>
      <div class="two">Ig</div>
      <div class="three">Tw</div>
    </div>

    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro ut, animi iure sequi voluptatem maiores, aspernatur tempora, ipsa tempore, voluptate sint. Maiores quos inventore cumque reiciendis iusto illum, aut quam, suscipit temporibus veniam. Reprehenderit distinctio velit eveniet blanditiis, animi optio voluptas dolores repellendus ad itaque veritatis. Expedita deserunt, ab dolor accusamus sequi eum optio. Fuga dolorum, quod qui laboriosam iure molestiae magnam explicabo! Accusamus, alias, non. Eius voluptas in aspernatur natus illo et possimus optio, cupiditate saepe quisquam totam laboriosam ullam nihil consequatur rem earum ratione perspiciatis. Quo impedit ipsum assumenda suscipit unde inventore dolores quas? Ipsa aliquam sapiente rerum sit autem magni ad dolore iste vero optio saepe, impedit eveniet suscipit, deserunt. Modi architecto laudantium placeat beatae repellat harum deleniti facere deserunt officia unde mollitia error praesentium, sunt fugit recusandae soluta facilis earum voluptatem libero consectetur illum debitis quos! Odit unde, quo non blanditiis vitae aperiam obcaecati provident praesentium quas qui, veritatis enim accusamus iusto rerum harum porro maxime sit amet cum odio suscipit ipsum nulla adipisci. Totam consectetur quas ipsa. Natus officiis, eveniet reprehenderit neque rem sint eum, ratione, numquam blanditiis nisi culpa repudiandae nemo beatae. Ea cum officiis vel, sed distinctio, voluptatibus quibusdam! Soluta voluptate, non facilis?</h1>
  </main>


<script src="main.js">

</script>
```

Comment: Your issue is that your overriding the transform instead, You should chain the transformations `transform: rotateZ(-90deg) translateX(-120px);`

Comment: I can't chain them, because one occurs when I scroll up and the onther one occurs when I scroll down.

Comment: Why not use `left` and `right` properties to move it in and out of the viewport ?

Comment: I did, but in this case there's no transition time

Comment: By default have `left:0`  Then in class `.hide` change to `left:-50px` or something

Comment: _"I can't chain them, because one occurs when I scroll up and the onther one occurs when I scroll down"_, You should still be able to chain them: https://jsfiddle.net/6spyd23z/1/

Comment: What's your expected output?

Answer (score 2):

Your hide class should not only apply the translate, but also the rotation, like so:

```css
.share.hide {
  transform: translateX(-120px) rotateZ(-90deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `left: -120px` instead of transform: translate(-120px) ?  You need absolute or relative position for this though. And when it should appear, set `left: 0`

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

I managed to move it out of the viewport while maintaining the `transform: rotateZ()` proterty and the `transition` time, using:

```
margin-left: -35px;.
```

**ALSO**, as @Zohir Salak and @Turnip suggested in the comments above, chaining `transform: rotateZ()` with `transform: translateX()` on the same line, works as well.

```js
const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
const nav = document.querySelector('nav');


burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
  nav.classList.toggle('active');
  burger.classList.toggle('hide');
  xicon.classList.toggle('active');
});

const xicon = document.querySelector('.xicon');
xicon.addEventListener('click', function() {
  nav.classList.toggle('active');
  xicon.classList.toggle('active');
  burger.classList.toggle('hide');
})



const header = document.querySelector('header');
let prev = window.pageYOffset;

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
  let current = window.pageYOffset;

  if(prev < current){
    header.classList.add('hide');
  }
  else {
    header.classList.remove('hide');
    }

    prev = current;

})


const shareThing = document.querySelector('.share');
let prevScroll = window.pageYOffset;

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  let currentScroll = window.pageYOffset;

  if(prevScroll < currentScroll) {
    shareThing.classList.add('hide');
    icons.classList.add('hide');
  }
  else {
    shareThing.classList.remove('hide');
    icons.classList.remove('hide');
  }

  prevScroll = currentScroll;

})


let share = document.querySelector('.share');
let icons = document.querySelector('.side');

share.addEventListener('click', () => {
  icons.classList.toggle('active');
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.logoandicon {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background: powderblue;
  padding: .7em 0;
}

.logo {
  margin-left: .5em;
}

.burger {
  margin-right: 1em;
  z-index: 2;
}

.burger.hide {
  display: none;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-family: verdana;
}

nav ul li {
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
}

nav {
  padding: 1em 0;
  line-height: 2em;
  background: lightgreen;
  display: none;
}

nav.active {
  display: block;
}

.xicon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1em;
  display: none;
}

.xicon.active {
  display: block;
}

header {
  width: 100vw;
  position: fixed;
}

header.hide {
  display: none;
}

main {
  padding-top: 4em;
}

.one {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

.two {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: green;
  color: white;
}

.three {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
}

.side {
  width: 30px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  background: black;
  display: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.side.active {
  display: flex;
}

.side.hide {
  display: none;
}

.share {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  transform: rotateZ(-90deg);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  padding: .15em 1em;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  transition: 1s;
}

.share.hide {
  margin-left: -35px;
}

/*OR
.share.hide {
  transform: rotateZ(-90deg) translateX(-120px);
  } /*
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

  <header>
    <div class="logoandicon">
      <h1 class="logo">Logo</h1>
      <img src="menu.svg" class="burger" width="30px" alt="burger-icon">
      <img src="xicon.svg" class="xicon" width="27px" alt="x-icon">
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <main>

    <p class="share">Share</p>
    <div class="side">
      <div class="one">Fb</div>
      <div class="two">Ig</div>
      <div class="three">Tw</div>
    </div>

    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro ut, animi iure sequi vol uptatem maiores, aspernatur tempora, ipsa tempore, voluptate sint. Maiores quos inventore cumque reiciendis iusto illum, aut quam, suscipit temporibus veniam. Reprehenderit distinctio velit eveniet blanditiis, animi optio voluptas dolores repellendus ad itaque veritatis. Expedita deserunt, ab dolor accusamus sequi eum optio. Fuga dolorum, quod qui laboriosam iure molestiae magnam explicabo! Accusamus, alias, non. Eius voluptas in aspernatur natus illo et possimus optio, cupiditate saepe quisquam totam laboriosam ullam nihil consequatur rem earum ratione perspiciatis. Quo impedit ipsum assumenda suscipit unde inventore dolores quas? Ipsa aliquam sapiente rerum sit autem magni ad dolore iste vero optio saepe, impedit eveniet suscipit, deserunt. Modi architecto laudantium placeat beatae repellat harum deleniti facere deserunt officia unde mollitia error praesentium, sunt fugit recusandae soluta fuptatem maiores, aspernatur tempora, ipsa tempore, voluptate sint. Maiores quos inventore cumque reiciendis iusto illum, aut quam, suscipit temporibus veniam. Reprehenderit distinctio velit eveniet blanditiis, animi optio voluptas dolores repellendus ad itaque veritatis. Expedita deserunt, ab dolor accusamus sequi eum optio. Fuga dolorum, quod qui laboriosam iure molestiae magnam explicabo! Accusamus, alias, non. Eius voluptas in aspernatur natus illo et possimus optio, cupiditate saepe quisquam totam laboriosam ullam nihil consequatur rem earum ratione perspiciatis. Quo impedit ipsum assumenda suscipit unde inventore dolores quas? Ipsa aliquam sapiente rerum sit autem magni ad dolore iste vero optio saepe, impedit eveniet suscipit, deserunt. Modi architecto laudantium placeat beatae repellat harum deleniti facere deserunt officia unde mollitia error praesentium, sunt fugit recusandae soluta facilis earum voluptatem libero consectetur illum debitis quos! Odit unde, quo non blanditiis vitae aperiam obcaecati provident praesentium quas qui, veritatis enim accusamus iusto rerum harum porro maxime sit amet cum odio suscipit ipsum nulla adipisci. Totam consectetur quas ipsa. Natus officiis, eveniet reprehenderit neque rem sint eum, ratione, numquam blanditiis nisi culpa repudiandae nemo beatae. Ea cum officiis vel, sed distinctio, voluptatibus quibusdam! Soluta voluptate, non facilis?</h1>
  </main>


<script src="main.js">

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Still don't understand why there is no overflow tho.

Comment: Where did you add that to?